# send details, address and google map location to email

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, gps, location

I wanted to create a form on my web site where a user can enter his/her details and have a small google map displayed on the page where he/she can click on it, find their location so that he/she can then send all the info along with the google map location to an email.

I've seen websites capable of doing this. 
Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you